# PageControl Changing issue when Tab hidden : Suggestions?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I have a PageControl with seven TabSheets and all Tabs are hidden and I change pages using pcMain.ActivePage:=tsAuto (tsMarine etc.) It works, but the Change and Changing events do not get fired.

I tried the following, but it only works when Tabs are visible.
http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2005/a/bltip0205_5.htm

I also wrote a procedure using pcMain.SelectNextPage(True) incrementing and decrementing a counter and the SelectNextPage but it also only works when Tabs are visible.

Anyone have a suggestion how to get around this issue? I need to use the AllowChange of the Changing-Event to prevent leaving a page if a Database is in an Edit-state.

Comment: You can call your update code yourself whenever you assign to `ActivePage`

Comment: David, but that makes for seven unique calls in my case, to get around the lack of firing the Changing Event.

Comment: Whenever you assign the `ActivePage` manually, just call the PageControl's currently assigned `OnChanging/OnChange` event handlers directly.  To help automate that, wrap the assignment and event call in a helper function that you can call when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The code from About.com should work fine. It explicitly calls `CanChange` and `Change`, which in turn call the event handlers, if any are assigned. They do not check whether the requested tab is visible.

Furthermore, `SelectNextPage` should also work. You just have to make sure you pass `False` for the second parameter to tell it to disregard tab visibility. (If you don't specify a value for the second parameter, the default value is `True`.)

If neither technique works, then you need to dig deeper because the problem is elsewhere.

One other thing you can try is to simply not assign a new active page if there are pending database changes. You're the one deciding to go the next page, after all. If you know in advance that it shouldn't happen, then don't attempt it in the first place.

Comment: There are bugs with Delphi `TPageControl` when tabs are hidden that Emba won't fix (e.g. [QC49135](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=49135)). Now, I don't know if those bugs are related to the problem here but it's certainly possible.

Comment: @David, the function described in that report doesn't exist in Delphi 2005, so I suspect it doesn't exist in prior versions, either.

Comment: Looking at my D6 code I rather suspect that the bugs relating to hidden tabs are even worse than in modern Delphi. I guess that `PageIndexFromTabIndex` was added to fix these bugs but it didn't fix the bugs 100%.

Comment: Rob, "should" does not cut it. I had said it doesn't work with the Tabs hidden. The ActivePageIndex does NOT increment when Tabs are hidden. As others are pointing out, overall, the PageControl is a mess. I have taken another approach using forms and Parent controls, and to hell with the PC.